Can satelite polar orbits be stable with a space elevator?
One issue with a space elevator, if all other hurdles are overcome, is that satellites on most orbits will crash into the cable. It has been suggested that satellites use polar orbits. However, the elevator spins with the equator. Can any passive satellite polar orbit be stable?

Over timescales up to a few decades, yes, satellites in passive polar orbits could synchronise their orbital period with a 24h equatorial space elevator and pass from pole to pole in safety.
However, orbits of all satellites decay.  For further reading try this early re-entry simulation which contains a link to early reentry studies.
